# 'ALTER table' for all tables in a database

Tags: mysql

How can I run the following for every table in a database:

```
ALTER table [table_name] type=innodb;
```

I don't want to have to manually run it for each table, but rather run it for all tables in a database.
As an aside: If your curious as to why I am running this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341  & http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1287

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your have your credentials and connection information setup on your my.cnf a command like this may do what you want.

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute \
'select concat("alter table ",TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME," type=innodb;") 
 from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | mysql
```

Replace database_name with your database name.

As for you main issue.  It sounds like you want to reclaim space after letting your innodb tables get large.  Like the bug said, the only safe way to deal with this is to use mysqldump to export everything.  Delete the files and then restore.

As that article notes.  You can enable `innodb_file_per_table` option to your server's my.cnf will make each file exist as a separate file.  That way reclaiming space can be done by deleting/restoring the problem table instead of everything.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: Instead of type= now engine= seems to be needed:


`mysql --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select concat("alter table ",TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME,E," engine=innodb;")   
 from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | mysql`


For checking your output simply pipe into less instead of mysql:

`mysql --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select concat("alter table ",TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME,E," engine=innodb;")   
 from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | less`

Comment: As I ran into an issue with escaping database and tables names, here is an escaped version:


`mysql --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select concat("ALTER TABLE \`",TABLE_SCHEMA,"\`.\`",TABLE_NAME,"\` ENGINE=innodb;")  
 FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | mysql`

Answer (score 2):

About Zoredache's answer (which has been very useful for me, thank you): **--skip-column-names** should be used to remove the headline.

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names -e \ 
'select concat("alter table ",TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME," type=innodb;")  
 from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | mysql
```

Comment: This is no longer needed, the command above was updated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which language you're using, but you can probably just run:

```
show table status from `DATABASE`;
```

Then loop through the result set, generating a query for each.